# Finding a formula for the Cantor pairing function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to derive a formula for the Cantor pairing function which gives a bijection between $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. There are some other questions and internet sources that give the formula, but I haven't found any that explain where it comes from. (For this, $\mathbb{N}$ excludes $0$.)

There is a suggested strategy in the problem statement.

> 1. Find $\phi(k-1,1)$, which is the number of points of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ on the first $k-1$ diagonals.
> 2. Observe that $\phi(1,k) = \phi(k-1,1) + 1$.
> 3. Observe that $\phi(m, k + 1 - m) = \phi(k-1, 1) + m$.
> 4. Then write a formula $\phi(m,n)$ in terms of $m,n$.

My first confusion is that it refers to $k-1$, which really requires me to say "first $k-1$ diagonals assuming $k \geq 2$." I'm already having difficulty seeing how this generalizes to a formula for any $m,n$.

It makes sense to me, giving this diagonal process of selecting points, that $\phi(k-1,1)$ is really the "number of elements previously enumerated," i.e., on its diagonal and all of the previous diagonals. This means that
$$
\phi(k-1,1) = \frac{(k-1)k}{2}.
$$
The second step does not make intuitive sense to me, though I was able to write out and verify it for $k=2,3,4$. I tried, unsuccessfully, to do the same for 3, but I think I must be missing the intuition.

I would appreciate some help on understanding how to use this process.

Comment: Please avoid asking questions for which a solution can be immediately found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function).

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Wikipedia provides only a formula. I acknowledged that formulas could be found elsewhere. I'm interested only in where it comes from and how to follow the steps in the problem statement.